# Deploy an empty pod that sits idle in k8's NameSpace

Tags: linux, kubernetes, containers

Can anyone help in making me understand if it's possible to deploy an empty pod inside a node in k8's for basic network debugging.PS : I should be able to `exec` this pod after its deployed.

Comment: Hello. what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Just deploy a pod with a container you need and command which do nothing.

Save that spec to a yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: empty
spec:
  containers:
  - name: empty
    image: alpine
    command: ["cat"]
```

And then apply that yaml by `kubectl apply -f $filename`

Comment: this is not working, because OP asked for a pod that stays alive. Replace ["cat"] by ["sleep", "10000000"] to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `kubectl` with [generator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/#generators).

```
# Create an idle pod
$ kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 idle-pod -i --tty --image ubuntu -- bash
root@idle-pod:/# # Debug whatever you want inside the idle container
root@idle-pod:/# exit
$

# Exec into idle pod
$ kubectl exec -i --tty idle-pod bash
root@idle-pod:/# # Debug whatever you want inside the idle container
root@idle-pod:/# exit
$

# Delete the idle pod
$ kubectl delete pod idle-pod
pod "idle-pod" deleted
$
```

Comment: The problem with `kubectl run` is that it is very limited in the options and it is difficult to create a custom pod, with registry credentials, secrets, env variables, labels, etc.